# Python: parse xml file built up with dicts

Tags: python, xml

[Python 3.4][Windows 7]

If there is any easy way to get a whole .xml file like a .txt as one string, that would be enough, but to describe the problem precisely:

This is the first time for me to deal with a .xml file.
I have a .xml file containing mainly dictionaries (of further dictionaries).
It also says 
now, i want to get very certain keys and values out of the dictionaries and write them in a .txt file, so therefore a dict (or sth else) in python would be enough.

To make an example:

This is the xml file (library.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Version<\key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>0001</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>spam</string>
            <key>Detail</key><string>spam spam</string>
        </dict>
        <key>0002</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>ham</string>
            <key>Detail</key><string>ham ham</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I researched and thought i can do it with the xml.etree.ElementTree module:
So if i try this:

```
tree = ET.parse('library.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

I only get this message:

(Unicode Error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes…

What I want is obviously some kind of this (or as a dict, it doesnt matter)

```
[['Name: spam', 'Detail: spam spam'], ['Name: ham', 'Detail: ham ham']
```

EDIT: xml code was incorrect, sry
EDIT: Added last paragraph

Comment: What should be output of these input???

Comment: just added this to the question, hope this is what you meant?

Comment: You can solve this from the standard library using `plistlib`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just wanted to let u know that i've just solved it this way:

```
with open('library.xml',
          'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
```

(and some regular expression to get the dicts i want)

this is probably very inefficient since i read the complete file as text but actually i dont care about efficiency, because the function has only one call in my program ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Python standard library contains a module that reads plist files: [`plistlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html). You can use it to solve your problem with an import and one command:

```
import plistlib

print plistlib.readPlist('library.xml')
```

Output:

```
{'Tracks': {'0001': {'Detail': 'spam spam', 'Name': 'spam'},
  '0002': {'Detail': 'ham ham', 'Name': 'ham'}},
 'Version': 1}
```

Comment: this might work but i guess my xml file is too long since my python crashes  when i try this^^

Comment: Try loading the file without printing it first. How big is your file?

Answer (score 0):

Update input content from `<\key>` to `</key>` and removed `dict` tag because key is not define for that.

1. Parse XML data by `lxml.html` module.
2. Get target main `dict` tag by `xpath()` method.
3. Call `XMLtoDict()` function.
4. Iterate on children of input tag by `getchildren()` method and `for` loop.
5. Check tag name is key or not by `if` loop.
6. If yes then get next tag of current tag by `getnext()` method.
7. If next tag is `integer` tag then get value type `int`.
8. If next tag is `string` tag then value type is `string`.
9. If next tag is `dict` tag then value type is `dict` and call function again i.e. recursive call.
10. Add key and value into result dictionary.
11. return result dictionary.
12. print result dictionary.

code:

```
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Version</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Tracks</key>
        <dict>
            <key>0001</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key><string>spam</string>
                <key>Detail</key><string>spam spam</string>
            </dict>
            <key>0002</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key><string>ham</string>
                <key>Detail</key><string>ham ham</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
"""

def XMLtoDict(root):
    result = {}
    for i in root.getchildren():
        if i.tag=="key":
            key = i.text
            next_tag = i.getnext()
            next_tag_name = next_tag.tag
            if next_tag_name=="integer":
                value = int(next_tag.text)
            elif next_tag_name=='string':
                value = next_tag.text
            elif next_tag_name=='dict':
                value = XMLtoDict(next_tag)
            else:
                value = None
            result[key] = value

    return dict(result)


import lxml.html as ET
import pprint

root = ET.fromstring(data)
result = XMLtoDict(root.xpath("//plist/dict")[0])
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 12.py 
{'Tracks': {'0001': {'Detail': 'spam spam', 'Name': 'spam'},
            '0002': {'Detail': 'ham ham', 'Name': 'ham'}},
 'Version': 1}
```

---

1. I am not getting such exception.

   (Unicode Error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes…
2. Tagging not correct in library.xml

   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   tree = ET.parse('library.xml')

Get following exception for input

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 12.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "12.py", line 46, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('library.xml')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1183, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 15
```

This exception due to invalid tagging. To fix this exception, do following:

Change from `<key>Version<\key>` to `<key>Version</key>`

3. By `xml.etree.ElementTree`  module:

code:

```
def XMLtoDict(root):
    result = {}
    chidren_tags = root.getchildren()
    for j, i in enumerate(chidren_tags):
        if i.tag=="key":
            key = i.text
            next_tag = chidren_tags[j+1]
            next_tag_name = next_tag.tag
            if next_tag_name=="integer":
                value = int(next_tag.text)
            elif next_tag_name=='string':
                value = next_tag.text
            elif next_tag_name=='dict':
                value = XMLtoDict(next_tag)
            else:
                value = None
            result[key] = value

    return dict(result)


def XMLtoList(root):
    result = []
    chidren_tags = root.getchildren()
    for j, i in enumerate(chidren_tags):
        if i.tag=="key":
            key = i.text
            next_tag = chidren_tags[j+1]
            next_tag_name = next_tag.tag
            if next_tag_name=="integer":
                value = int(next_tag.text)
            elif next_tag_name=='string':
                value = next_tag.text
            elif next_tag_name=='dict':
                value = XMLtoList(next_tag)
            else:
                value = None
            result.append([key, value])

    return list(result)


import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pprint

tree = ET.parse('library.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

dict_tag = root.find("dict")
if dict_tag is not None:
    result = XMLtoDict(dict_tag)
    print "Result in Dictinary:-"
    pprint.pprint(result)

    result = XMLtoList(dict_tag)
    print "\nResult in Dictinary:-"
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

output:
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 12.py

```
Result in Dictinary:-
{'Tracks': {'0001': {'Detail': 'spam spam', 'Name': 'spam'},
            '0002': {'Detail': 'ham ham', 'Name': 'ham'}},
 'Version': 1}

Result in Dictinary:-
[['Version', 1],
 ['Tracks',
  [['0001', [['Name', 'spam'], ['Detail', 'spam spam']]],
   ['0002', [['Name', 'ham'], ['Detail', 'ham ham']]]]]]
```

Comment: i dont get this sry^^

first of all with your code there is an ImportError: No module named 'lxml'

second: creating the dict or sth like that was not my problem, my problem is that your variable data is a .xml file, and i can not open it the normal way with the command open(...)

Comment: @Rynos: Update answer. 1. I am not getting exception  `(Unicode Error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes…` so can you email me library.xml on vivekbsable.gmail.com because there might be some hidden characters in file cause issue. 2. Used `lxml.html` because this have many more feature then `ElementTree` like `getnext()` tag. You need to install to fix ` ImportError: No module named 'lxml'` exception.  Let me know if you need more hlp,  can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.